# Извлечь строку из переменной, переданной в параметре

Tags: perl

У меня есть скрипт на PERL, в который мне нужно передать два аргумента `arg0` и `arg1`. Я хочу проанализировать `arg1` и извлечь только необходимые мне значения. Пример:

```
./telnet 10.10.1.1 72-0/1/1
```

После я хочу, чтобы в моём скрипте переменная `arg1` принимала только значение `0/` и не `72-0/`.

Может кто-нибудь помочь?

Answer (score 2):

Параметры командной строки находятся в массиве @ARGV. Можно легко посмотреть его содержимое:

```
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
print Dumper \@ARGV;
```

Извлеките оттуда любой нужный по счету параметр.

Answer (score 0):

> я хочу, чтобы в моём скрипте переменная `arg1` принимала только
>   значение `0/` и не `72-0/`

Для начала более чётко сформулируйте критерии, по которым нужно обрабатывать аргумент и что из чего должно получаться. Потому что при такой постановке вопроса задача вообще решается прямолинейно:

```
$ARGV[1] = '0/';
```

Или, например, так:

```
$ARGV[1] = '0/' if $ARGV[1] && !index $ARGV[1], '72-0/';
```

Или, может быть, имеется в виду что-то вроде этого?

```
$ARGV[1] =~ s{^\d+[-](\d+/).*$}{$1};
```